# jenkins installation windows 10 "Service Logon Credentials"

Tags: jenkins

I don't know Jenkins at all. I want to install Jenkins on Windows 10. I downloaded the installer and ran it, but I have a problem. I don't know what to enter in the "Account" and "Password" fields on the "Service Logon Credentials" stage.

[image: Screen of where I got stuck - Service Logon Credentials]

if I use the username and password of my Windows account(with administrator privileges) the following information is displayed:

[image: Test Credentials information]

Comment: Please see [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63543810/598141). Can't mark a duplicate since ithas not been answered.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

> When installing a service to run under a domain user account, the account must have the right to logon as a service. This logon permission applies strictly to the local computer and must be granted in the Local Security Policy.
>
> Perform the following to edit the Local Security Policy of the computer you want to define the ‘logon as a service’ permission:
>
> 1. Logon to the computer with administrative privileges.
> 2. Open the **Administrative Tools** and open the **Local Security Policy**
> 3. If the **Local Security Policy** is missing in your system, refer to the answer in the [Where to download GPEdit.msc for Windows 10 Home?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/where-to-download-gpeditmsc-for-windows-10-home/c39bd656-8d4a-4374-be39-394c09deec4e) question on Microsoft Community to troubleshoot
> 4. Expand **Local Policy** [Note: it's **... Policies** on Win Server] and click on **User Rights Assignment**
> 5. In the right pane, right-click **Log on as a service** and select properties.
> 6. Click on the **Add User or Group…** button to add the new user.
> 7. In the **Select Users or Groups** dialogue, find the user you wish to enter and click **OK**
> 8. Click **OK** in the **Log on as a service Properties** to save changes.
>
> Then try again with the added user.

– [Jenkins User Handbook > Windows > Invalid service logon credentials](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/windows/#invalid-service-logon-credentials)

Comment: Thank you it worked for me as well.  Using the same steps I edited the Group service policy.

Comment: I followed these steps but Jenkins still said the password/user was incorrect, only solution i found was to install with the not recommended option

Comment: @ChanakaKarunarathne Any idea on what setting will help on Windows 10 Home as it does not contain local security policy settings.

Comment: @RaviBhatt This might help.. 
https://www.majorgeeks.com/content/page/how_to_enable_local_security_policy_in_windows_10_home.html

Comment: failed for me with latest msi today.

Comment: This does not answer what is the account credential needed to use here

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS I guess it's obvious. If anyone didn't get it, Use the username and password of your Windows account.

Comment: On 3 it's Local Policies

Comment: I am not able to find 'Local Security Policy' in ‘Administrative Tools’. Without that not able to move forward. Please help me.

Comment: @RadadiyaNikunj Search "'Local Security Policy" in the start menu.

Comment: @ChanakaKarunarathne There are no results when I search 'Local Security Policy' in the start menu.

Comment: For Windows 11 users only - Please consider windows tools instead of Administrative tools. Rest all process will be same. 
PS: Make sure your Pc is having a password.(Its mandatory for installation)

Comment: This is not working for me, Machine Windows 10

Answer (score 11):

Below solution worked for me on Windows10.

1. Select Logon Type = Run Service as Local System ,click Install and complete the setup
2. To unlock Jenkins, Go to C:\Program Files\Jenkins and open jenkins.err
3. Get Administrator password ,paste and Install suggested plugins.
4. Create first admin user and start using Jenkins

Answer (score 8):

Follow [Chanaka Karunarathne](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63410442/9153063)'s answer, just in the 'enter the object name to select' section enter your PC's user name. If you do not know what is your user name then just open a command prompt and run 'whoami'.

Answer (score 5):

I followed this procedure to install Jenkins and it worked like a charm,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_Zs0gQq1Yc

Step1:
Download the "jenkins.war" file.

Step 2:
Run this command `java -jar jenkins.war`

Step 3:
Copy the secret that you get from this location,

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\secrets\initialAdminPassword
```

Use this Key when prompted to "Unlock Jenkins",
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are a windows 10 home user, you need to download and install GPEdit.msc in Windows 10 Home using PowerShell script before you can use "Local Security Policy". you can download it from [here](https://www.itechtics.com/enable-gpedit-windows-10-home/#Download_and_Install_GPEditmsc_in_Windows_10_Home_using_PowerShell_script).

Answer (score 1):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63582616/15182613) is correct. In addition to that, if you don't have any additional local user in your PC then create a local user(any username is ok) and provide the credentials to the logon credentials. don't forget to follow the process mentioned in the answer reference.

Answer (score 0):

I was be able to follow https://stackoverflow.com/users/4309588/chanaka-karunarathne's suggestion, but when it went to the next step, I tried to enter my "admin"(aka laptop login credentials), in my case I usually login with the 4-digit code to my Windows; and even if I use the password associated with the account, it would be my email as username and it's windows password as password, but I have setup two-step authentication for my email as well. it would not work.

I ended up username + 4 digit pass-code would not work on this
username(email  address) + password would not work as well (due to the MFA)

I don't know why it had to be this difficult to login to Jenkins (or not sure if I should be upset about myself for setting up MFA for my email :) )

Comment: You shouldn't like the user but the *suggestion*.

Answer (score 0):

@elysium You can solve such problem by switching from **Microsoft Account** to **Local Account** for your computer. On assuming that your computer is similar to mine, you can navigate as follows;

Press/Click the Microsoft Windows tab on your keyboard.
Navigate to your profile picture and click on "**Change Account Settings**"
Navigate to Log in with Local Account instead and make the switch from Microsoft Account to Local Account.

Follow @Chanaka Karunarathne 's instructions. If you cannot find **Local Security Policy**, Go to search and type **winver** to confirm if you are using either of this OS versions ; **Windows 10 Pro**, Windows 10 Education, Windows 10 Pro Edu, Windows 10 Enterprise, Windows 10 Pro Workstation) otherwise **Windows 10 Home** lucks Local Security Policy, atleast for my case.

Alternatively, as mentioned in some previous comments here, to **enable Group policy in Windows 10 Home**, download a from here, right click on it run as administrator. Press Window Key + R, type **gpedit.msc** to check if Group policy has been enabled as described in this majorgeeks youtube channel (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7wkgwEhtqdI&ab_channel=majorgeeks)

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 11, I am getting the same error even though provided user and password are correct. So I have installed Jenkins as LocalSystem.

After completion of installation, I changed it from the services and it worked for me. [image]

Comment: Where do we get the password for the Jenkins Properties field?