# Safe-restart Jenkins throw an exception

Tags: jenkins

I am new to Jenkins. Here I have tried to restart Jenkins putting down this into cmd.

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ -webSocket safe-restart
```

Unfortunatly, I got this stacktrace

```
ERROR: Unexpected exception occurred while performing safe-restart command.
   hudson.lifecycle.RestartNotSupportedException: Default Windows lifecycle does not support restart.
    at hudson.lifecycle.Lifecycle$1.verifyRestartable(Lifecycle.java:84)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.restartableLifecycle(Jenkins.java:4305)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.safeRestart(Jenkins.java:4339)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.doSafeRestart(Jenkins.java:4294)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.cli.declarative.MethodBinder.call(MethodBinder.java:114)
    at hudson.cli.declarative.CLIRegisterer$1.main(CLIRegisterer.java:218)
    at hudson.cli.CLIAction$ServerSideImpl.run(CLIAction.java:277)
    at hudson.cli.CLIAction$1.lambda$opened$0(CLIAction.java:148)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How can I solve this problem? (Safely restart jenkins from cmd)

Comment: How did you launch Jenkins? Is it running asa service?

Comment: I have just install .war jenkins file and use java -jar ... to tun it

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the jenkins.war from the cmd line, either Linux or Windows, you cannot restart Jenkins. The application must be running as a service or a daemon (Java service wrapper OK too) for restart to work.

You can `safeExit`, then relaunch the app from the cmd line again.

Or, use the new Windows installer, but [read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63410442/598141) and [my comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63546100/598141) on the installer.