# Jenkins installation windows 11 Home edition "Service Logon Credentials"

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, devops

I want to install Jenkins on Windows 11. I downloaded the installer and ran it, but I have a problem. I don't know what to enter in the "Account" and "Password" fields on the "Service Logon Credentials" stage.
There's a recommendation to modify User Rights assignment in Windows Local Policy which I don't seem to be able to do because I am running windows 11 Home edition

[image: Running Windows 11 Home Edition]

I get to choose the recommended option : run service as local

[image: I choose the recommended option]

The error message I receive.

[image: I get this error whenever I use my windows username and password]

Comment: Have you provided your local administrator account details?

Comment: Yes @DhavalGajjar

Comment: This [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69391227/17071589) answer worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Below solution worked for me on Windows 11 home.

1. Select Logon Type = Run Service as Local System, click Install and complete the setup
2. In your browser open localhost:8080
3. To unlock Jenkins, Go to C:\Program Files\Jenkins and open jenkins.err Get Administrator password, paste and Install suggested plugins.
4. Create first admin user and start using Jenkins